# Microsoft IIS Server - Warning - REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE

Tags: iis, iis-express, url-rewrite-module

We have recently noticed that our Microsoft IIS server is producing lots of log files, apparently because of a warning that is thrown for every request. The event where the warning occurs is

> REWRITE_DISABLED_KERNEL_CACHE

We have enabled HTTPS for the server just recently, so maybe it has something to do with that. Here's a section of one of these warnings:
[image]

I assume it would be safe to just configure the server for ignoring this warning because I didn't find any other possible solutions, but my experience with microsoft server administration is very limited.

The endpoints are called by a polling mechanism from many clients and apparently the servers stopped working when the polling interval was too small (<15sec). Could the server be crashing from too many log files (considering that each file is ~200kb)?

Comment: “our Microsoft IIS server is producing lots of log files”, so in which folder did you see the files?

Comment: There are similar questions here you can use as a reference: [https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/599160/trace-warning-rewrite-disabled-kernel-cache.html](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/599160/trace-warning-rewrite-disabled-kernel-cache.html).